# dataframe cleaning: removing a specific number of zeros from a column in pandas-

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I need help removing unwanted zeros from a data frame. The column values are integers and I'm not exactly sure how to remove the zeros from the 'Year' column. As shown in the image below, (highlighted in blue), I'm trying to remove the zeros after '2014'. (there are a few other values like this in this column)

[image: screenshot of dataset]

Answer (score 1):

You can filter first 4 values in column `Year` by converting to strings with `str[:4]`:

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str).str[:4].astype(int)
```